# geth sync status is not clear

Tags: go-ethereum

I just started the sync from scratch about 20 hours ago by running `geth --rpc --fast --cache=1024`.

What I can see now in console is that the last block that was synced is `number=3918966`
`count=13 elapsed=11.009ms number=3918966 hash=2c8144…c066ee ignored=0 INFO [06-25|16:33:27] Imported new state entries`

After that it is just counting in console like this:

`count=55 flushed=45 elapsed=27.008ms processed=6452838 pending=11692 retry=10 duplicate=1208 unexpected=4863
INFO [06-25|20:28:11] Imported new state entries
count=384  flushed=428 elapsed=26.019ms  processed=8494218 pending=3621  retry=2   duplicate=1535 unexpected=7772
INFO [06-25|20:28:11] Imported new state entries`[image]

Does that means that sync is finished?

`eth.syncing` returns:

```
{                         
  currentBlock: 3927202,  
  highestBlock: 3927287,  
  knownStates: 8621554,   
  pulledStates: 8618011,  
  startingBlock: 3926371  
}
```

`eth.blockNumber` returns `0`

`...\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\geth\` folder size already reached 22 GB and I can tell that folder is continue to grow.

Comment: I raised the same question, hopefully this finds an answer... https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18709/geth-chaindata-copied-syncd-keystore-account-updated-balance-0-heavy-act?noredirect=1#comment19888_18709

Answer (score 5):

As long as the state entries  are still being processed you have not fully synced. When you are fully synced you should see blocks being processed like this:

```
INFO [07-26|12:45:27] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1    txs=0    mgas=0.000   elapsed=4.999ms   mgasps=0.000   number=1376235 hash=7613d4â€¦
```